# How to append date to a wmic nteventlog command

Tags: batch-file, time, wmic

How would I go about adding the date to the output filename for the log files with what I have right now. I've found 1 or 2 date commands but I can't seem to get them to work with what I have already.

I.E.: `ECHO %time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%`

```
@echo off
net use y: \\server_name\shared_folder_name /USER:admin password /persistent:yes
wmic nteventlog where filename='application' backupeventlog C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Application.evt
wmic nteventlog where filename='security' backupeventlog C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Security.evt
wmic nteventlog where filename='system' backupeventlog C:\Users\Public\Desktop\System.evt
wmic nteventlog where filename='application' cleareventlog
wmic nteventlog where filename='system' cleareventlog
wmic nteventlog where filename='security' cleareventlog
exit
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch File For Log Backup & Clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439340/batch-file-for-log-backup-clear)

Comment: Date time format varies by country.  What do you see if you do ECHO %DATE% %TIME%?  What are you wanting to be appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply WMIC to get the date too.  It's more robust than manipulating the %date% variable as that depends on locale and regional preferences.

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Comment: That works great. I can edit the date/time output format just the way I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Taking foxidrive answer (thank you, i never remember i can get time from wmi) and reorganizing your code (nothing wrong with your code, i prefer to separate task configuration from task execution)

```
@echo off
    rem prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions

    rem configuration
    set _logPath=C:\Users\Public\Desktop
    set _eventLogs=Application Security System "Internet Explorer"

    rem call subroutine for each of the event logs
    for %%e in (%_eventLogs%) do call :backupClearLog %%e "%_logPath%"

    rem cleanup
    endlocal 

    rem end of the work. exit batch file
    exit /b

:backupClearLog
    rem retrieve timestamp
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==.," %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set _timeStamp=%%a

    rem %~1 = log name, without quotes
    set _eventLog=%~1

    rem %~2 = directory to store backup, without quotes
    set _output="%~2\%_timeStamp%_%_eventLog%.evt"

    rem if you prefer timestamp as a suffix, use the following line instead
    set _output="%~2\%_eventLog%_%_timeStamp%.evt"

    rem Save Event Logs - Remove echo to make it work
    echo wmic nteventlog where filename='%_eventLog%' backupeventlog %_output%
    echo wmic nteventlog where filename='%_eventLog%' cleareventlog

    goto :EOF
```

I've included "Internet Explorer" in the list of event logs to reflect the usage in the case of logs with spaces in name.

Comment: This is certainly a more elegant solution in regard to structure and the nested function. However, I'm trying to keep it as simple as I can. Thank you for your help.